# Merge 2 SQL Server Instances?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have 2 SQL Server instances on a single server, inst1 and inst2. These are tightly coupled instance, with inst1 being linked to inst2 and vice-versa.

Because they are already running on the same server, I would like to merge them and cut this linked server mess. My question is: is it possible to merge them while "maintaining" the queries unaltered at day 0?

EG: `select * from table1 join linkedServer.database2.dbo.table2` would still run

Comment: I suggest you think **very carefully** about your "improvement". You don't seem to be solving a problem. You should consider (or ask!) why this situation exists, consult with everyone affected. and then move forward with a plan that addresses any concerns and contains a way to revert if something unanticipated happens. Everything external to the removed server instance will now need to be re-configured to access the remaining instance. Don't poke a sleeping bear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use what's often referred to as a loopback linked server for that.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'YourLinkedServerName',
    @srvproduct = N' ',
    @provider = N'SQLNCLI', 
    @datasrc = @@SERVERNAME
GO
```